# jQuery Sortable only one list still updated if cancelled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have 2 lists which are connected using jQuery sortable. When I move an item from one list to another, 2 ajax requests are made to a PHP script which updates a database with the content of the lists - this works fine.

However I then added a JavaScript confirm popup, and put the ajax requests in this condition when 'OK' is pressed. If I press 'Cancel' on this popup then this still works correctly - however if I 'Cancel' then the list which is having an item moved does not update, so both lists end up with the item.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {

    $(".week1").sortable({
      connectWith: ".week2, .week1"
    }).disableSelection();

  });

    $(".week1, .week2").on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {

        var answer = confirm("Move job?");
        if (!answer) {
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

            return false;
        }else{

            $('.week1, .week2').sortable({

                    update: function (event, ui) {

                        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

                        $.ajax({
                            data: data,
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'ajax_user_schedules.php'
                        })
                        .done(function( response ){
                            console.log( response );
                        });
                    }
                });

        }

    });
```

The problem makes sense because the code to update is in the `else` so the list that is having an item added will not run this code, I just don't know how to fix it.I tried separating the week1 and week2 sortables but that did not work, and if I take the update code out of this condition then I see a different problem - where if I cancel then the list having an item taken away is updated before the item is put back, so both lists end up without the item. There is something very wrong in what I'm doing.

Any help will be great!

Thanks,

UPDATE based on an answer

```
$(function() {

  $(".week1, .week2").sortable({
      connectWith: ".week2, .week1",
      update: function (event, ui) {
                var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

                console.log(this); // this is shown before confirm popup appears

                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax_user_schedules.php'
                })
                .done(function( response ){
                    console.log( response );
                });
            }

    }).disableSelection();

    $(".week1, .week2").on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {

        var answer = confirm("Move job?");
        if (!answer) {
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` clause reinitialises the sortables. It looks like you meant to have the `update` handler in the first `.sortable({})` initialiser; you don't need the `update` at all, as it triggers on every dom change. Just pull it to its own function:

```
$(".week1").sortable({
      connectWith: ".week2, .week1"

}).disableSelection();

    var update = function (sortable) {

            var data = $(sortable).sortable('serialize');

            $.ajax({
                 data: data,
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'ajax_user_schedules.php'
            })
            .done(function( response ){
                 console.log( response );
            });
      }
$(".week1, .week2").on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {

    var answer = confirm("Move job?");
    if (!answer) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

        return false;
    }
    else {
        update($(".week1"));
        update($(".week2"));
    }
});
```

(Also, the `.on(sortreceive)` handler binding should also be wrapped in a ready handler)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Please see the edit in my original post for my updated code. The problem now is that both ajax requests are being made, but the first (the list where an item is being move from) is done immediately - so both lists end up with no item. The console.log(this) i added is seen even before the confirm popup appears. Any ideas?

Comment: Shows what I know.. you probably don't want an `update` handler at all. I'll *update*